# I have taken my midterm exam 1 hour ago, and I am confused about some question meaning

Tags: logic, deduction

[image]

1 what is the defferenece between "the justification of line 6" and "the application of xx on line 6"? For example, we can find that in the line 6, the application is wrong because we need to use PC rather than ¬I, but I have no idea about if  "the application of ¬I on line 6 is false" equals to "the justificayion of line 6 is false". I mean, we can indeed prove that the conclusion in the  line 6 is correct.

So the statement "the justification of line 6", Does this statement become correct by only considering the correctness of this conclusion, or is it necessary for both the process and the formula symbols on the right to be correct for the statement to be correct?

2 If an error occurs in an earlier line, can we conclude that all subsequent lines, line x included, are incorrect? For example, if line 1 is incorrect ,can we conclude that "the justificayion of line x(x>1)"and "the application of xx on line x" are both false?Or is it that if there's an error in the previous formula application, it only affects subsequent "justification", not the inference "formula applications"?

To summary, What I want to know is the criteria for determining the correctness of these two statements "the justification of line 6" and "the application of xx on line 6", and whether errors in the previous application and justification would affect the subsequent assessments.

Comment: "what is the difference between "the justification of line 6" and "the application of xx on line 6"?" To "justify" a step in the deduction means to state what rule has been applied to what previous lines in the proof: thus, the two statements express the same meaning.

Comment: "the statement "the justification of line 6", Does this statement become correct by only considering the correctness of this conclusion, " It is not enough to state a correct formula to have a correct deduction: we have to justify it by a "correct move" (an application of a rule).

Comment: "If an error occurs in an earlier line, can we conclude that all subsequent lines, line x included, are incorrect?" In general, yes, because the subsequent lines will rely on the incorrect one.